# Calling fragment from a list adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-sliding

I am using sliding menu/drawer pattern in my app. So the main activity has a leftView which is a ListFragment named topicsFragment() which loads set of topic items. When an item/topic is clicked it replaces the fragment on main view by calling the FeedsFragment(tag). FeedsFragment uses arraylist adapter to load the feeds which has various clickable items in each list item. I want to fetch another instance on the feedsFragment(tag) when an item is clicked within a list item.

```
    holder.contextView= (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.arcHeader);
    if (item.hasArc()) {
        holder.contextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String arc;
        try {
            arc=item.getarc();
            holder.contextView.setText(arc);

            holder.contextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                //currently it loads a class
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                   Intent i = new Intent(context, SomeClass.class); 
                   i.putExtra("tag", arc);
                   context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        holder.contextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Currently it loads a new class. I want to define a fragment and then pass to main activity to replace with the current view but I cant use getSupportFragmentManager() inside an adapter class but only in a fragment or fragment activity. What should be an alternative to sweeping in a fragment from an adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by using the context passed in the list adapter:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment newFragment = new ListFragmentClass(tag);
    if (newFragment != null)
        switchFragment(newFragment);
}

private void switchFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    if (context == null)
        return;
    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity feeds = (MainActivity) context;
        feeds.switchContent(newFragment);
    }
}
```

Here switchContent is method defined in your main activity for switching/replacing fragment as given in answer by Justin V.

Comment: should'nt it be switchFragment(newFragment );  instead of  switchFragment(newContent);

Comment: and it is quite wierd `switchContent` and `switchFragment`. @Zoya should stick with one of them, not both.

Answer (score 3):

What I did was create this method in my main activity and just called it from other classes to change the fragment:

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
        mContent = fragment;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

        slidemenu.showContent();

    }
```

Comment: this method is what i wanted to call from the list adapter class, and hence the question. I solved it by using the 'application context' passed to the list adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `getFragmentManager()` as a parameter in constructor of your adapter and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Interface` to connect your side drawer `ListFragment` to the main activity. For example:

```
public class LeftDrawer extends ListFragment{

    private DrawerCallback mCallback;

    public interface DrawerCallback{
        public void onListClick(String tag);
    }

    public void setCallback(DrawerCallback callback){
        mCallback = callback;
    }

}
```

As `Fragments` should have an empty constructor, use a public method within your `Fragment` to set the callback before completing the `FragmentTransaction` adding it to your drawer. At this point all that is left is notifying your `Fragment` that a click has occurred. What you should do is actually catch the click in your `ListFragment` directly rather than adding on onClickListener to every view in your adapter.

```
 @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    /*
     * Get item at the clicked position from your adapter and
     * get its string tag before triggering interface
     */
   mCallback.onListClick(tag);
}
```

Use the onListItemClick method to do this. You will get the list position that was clicked and can easily then get that item from your adapter and get its tag value to pass back to your host activity.